# Programatically retrieve a block and print it in a page

Tags: 7, blocks

I have a form, generated by the Webform module, which is available as block. Now I want to retrieve the form itself and print it in a page.

How can I achieve this, programmatically? I'm using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure on which page you want to print the block. This is an example that prints the block in a custom page.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['my/page/path'] = array(
    'title' => 'Block in A Page',
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_block_page',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );    

  return $items;
} 

/**
 * The page callback which display the block
 */
function mymodule_block_page(){ 
  $block = module_invoke($module_name, 'block_view', $delta);

  return $block['content'];
}
```

[`hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) registers a menu path which will display the block. `mymodule_block_page()` is invoked when the menu path is accessed like http://example.com/my/page/path.

`module_invoke($module_name, 'block_view', $delta);` will return the block ready to render. Please find out the module name and delta. I guess `$module_name` would be **webform**. If you go to the block configuration, e.g. admin/structure/block/manage/comment/recent/configure, the module name is *comment* and the delta is *recent*.

If you want to print the block on every page except the front page, create a variable in `hook_preprocess_page()` of template.php.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (!drupal_is_front_page()) {
    // It is not the front page.
    $block = block_load('module_name', 'block-delta');
    $variables['myblock'] = _block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block)));   
  } 
}
```

In page.tpl.php, you can place the following code snippet where you want.

```
<?php if (isset($myblock)): ?>
  <?php print render($myblock); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```