# How do I render the block login on the front page?

Tags: 7, theming

I start making my own custom theme and I want to add the login page in mytheme, if the user is not logged-in; then show the block login on the front page.

How to render a block for the login in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Themes should not directly render blocks on its own, nor have an hard-coded list of blocks to render. Drupal provides a configuration page on admin/structure/block, which allows to set which blocks show for every every theme, and in which region.

> [image: screenshot]

The cases are two:

- The theme is used only on your own sites, or the ones you maintain. In this case, you can simply use the UI to set the blocks to show for that theme. If you need to enable the same blocks on different sites, and manually setting them for each site would be prohibitive, you can export the list of blocks as a feature, and import it for every site you need. (It requires the [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module.)
- Everybody can download the theme and use it. In this case, having a theme that renders blocks without giving the possibility to the users to select if rendering them can create an issue in at least two cases:

  - The user that can administer the blocks already selected the login block to be shown in a specific region. If the theme is always rendering the login block, users would see two login blocks.
  - The administrator user selected the theme as administrative theme, where trying to show the login block doesn't probably make sense. (The administrative theme is normally shown to logged-in users, for which the login block is never shown from Drupal.)

That said, you could render the login block from a template file using the following code.

```
$block = module_invoke('user', 'block_view', 'login');
print render($block['content']);
```

An installation profile (and a distribution) can enable blocks for a theme. See what the Standard profile does in [`standard_install()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/profiles%21standard%21standard.install/function/standard_install/7.x). (I edited the code to show a shorter list of blocks.)

```
  // Enable some standard blocks.
  $default_theme = variable_get('theme_default', 'bartik');
  $admin_theme = 'seven';
  $blocks = array(
    array(
      'module' => 'user',
      'delta' => 'login',
      'theme' => $default_theme,
      'status' => 1,
      'weight' => 0,
      'region' => 'sidebar_first',
      'pages' => '',
      'cache' => -1,
    ),
    array(
      'module' => 'system',
      'delta' => 'navigation',
      'theme' => $default_theme,
      'status' => 1,
      'weight' => 0,
      'region' => 'sidebar_first',
      'pages' => '',
      'cache' => -1,
    ),
    array(
      'module' => 'system',
      'delta' => 'powered-by',
      'theme' => $default_theme,
      'status' => 1,
      'weight' => 10,
      'region' => 'footer',
      'pages' => '',
      'cache' => -1,
    ),
  );
  $query = db_insert('block')->fields(array('module', 'delta', 'theme', 'status', 'weight', 'region', 'pages', 'cache'));
  foreach ($blocks as $block) {
    $query->values($block);
  }
  $query->execute();
```

Using code similar to that, a module or an installation profile can enable any block, knowing which module implements that block. Of course, 'theme' needs to be the machine name of the theme, so you need to change it to match the machine name of your theme.

Creating a distribution is an alternative of using features. I would suggest either one of them over having a theme that renders blocks on its own.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it using admin panel -

The Drupal block for signing in and signing up are the same. In the blocks area of the admin, the block is titled: "User login"

You could assign it to only show up on  (for the front page), and move it to whatever region you want.

---

You can render user login block with php using -

```
print(drupal_render(drupal_get_form("user_login"));
```

Got it from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194414/display-login-block-and-registration-block

Or if you want to do it using template.php there refer [Programatically retrieve a block and print it in a page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62377/programatically-retrieve-a-block-and-print-it-in-a-page)

Though not exaclty what you wanted but you can render login block the same way described in above url:)

Comment: There is no need to do this programmatically, when Drupal allows to set the blocks shown for each enabled themes.

Comment: Also, the User module already has a login block, so rendering the user login form is not necessary.

Comment: @kiamlaluno He is creating a custom theme, so i thought he might want a solution that uses code.

Comment: If he is creating a custom theme, which means a theme that will be used only on his own sites, or sites he maintains, he can enable the login block from admin/structure/block.